# How to pass value of a browse button in html to perl program

Tags: html, perl

I have a html page in which i am using a browse button which allows a user to browse for a file in his system. when i press a submit button,a perl script is called. i want to pass the value selected by the user to the perl program.

**Html code:**

```
<form NAME="form1" ACTION="/cgi-bin/sample.pl" METHOD="POST">
    <center>
        <input type="file" name="selectFile" />
    </center>
    <center>
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="B">
    </center>
</form>
```

**Perl Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);

$query = new CGI;

print "Content-Typr: text/plain\n\n";

$FileName = $query->param('selectFile'); #read the parameter passed from html page
```

can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have mis-spelled `Content-Type`

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of how to do file uploads in the [CGI documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#PROCESSING-A-FILE-UPLOAD-FIELD). You'll find everything you need there.